# Add Dropdown to a Text Field with AutoComplete in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, textfield, oracle-apex

Currently, I have an Text Field with AutoComplete item added to my page. I have a requirement to add a dropdown arrow button to the right of that item. The user should have the ability to use the features of AutoComplete but also have the ability to click the dropdown arrow to activate the list that appears from the AutoComplete item. For example, if the AutoComplete item is null and the user clicks the dropdown arrow, the list of all possible values should appear. However, if the user actually types something into the AutoComplete field, then the list of values will display specifically to what was keyed into the AutoComplete field.

Thus far I haven't come across any information online to help figure out how to achieve this task. Can anyone provide an solutions?

At the moment i have this functionality partially working... I have added the dropdown arrow as a button. When this button is clicked, it activates a dynamic action that executes JavaScript. The JavaScript I have is:

```
if ($(".ac_results").css("display") == "none"){
  $(".ac_results").css("display","block");
}
else{
  $(".ac_results").css("display","none");
}
```

This only works when the user has entered a value into the AutoComplete field (which initiates something in the background to create a  with the class .ac_results). Then, the user removes the value keyed in and then clicks the dropdown arrows. The list appears for a split second then is gone. But if the button is clicked again the list of values appear and disappear as they should with the button clicks.

Any suggestions or solutions would be wonderful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Select2 Plugin instead. It has all the features you're looking for and will save you a lot of time getting all the CSS correct. Demo of it: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=64237:20:0:

Comment: I attempted to use the Select2 Plugin and it wasn't working exactly how the demo's were. Perhaps I need to pay for it to get what I need? The demos of the plugin are exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I feel like the suggestion to use the Select2 plugin would have worked well if the application wasn't so custom. I will have to continue to figure out how to get this to work. If anyone else has a better suggestion i would love to read and learn about it.

Comment: Martin, can you share some documentation for `select2` plugin, where It's possible to sort out how to make `select2` inputs look the way standard apex select inputs look?